# Which of the Apple provided free iPhone 4 cases has a large free area for dock connectors?

Tags: iphone, accessories

I have an iPhone 4 and am contemplating which of the [free cases](http://www.apple.com/iphone/case-program/) I should get.

I bought a basic case at Best Buy when I bought my phone. The big problem I have with this one is that the opening at the bottom for the dock connector isn't large enough to connect the adaptor I have to play music in my car ([GROM iPod connector](http://www.gromaudio.com/store/aux_adapters/index.html) -- highly recommended).

Can anyone advise on which of hte free cases has a larger dock connector? For reference, the Apple Bumper is definitely *not* big enough.

Comment: Somebody with a big more reputation than me want to creat a "case" or "accessory" tag?

Comment: Oh darn. I didn't read the fine print. I had to get the free case within 30 days of purchase of my phone. Grrrrr

Comment: the link to the free cases program in non functional as the program ended Sep. 30th. 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Incase Snap Case through the free program, and it doesn't cover the bottom of the unit at all (except for the sides) so it should work for you, unless your dock connector is massive:

[image]

Comment: very nice -- what's the surface of the case like? hard plastic? rubbery? too grippy (i.e. hard to slip into your pocket)?

Comment: @Doug It seems similar to the soft-touch coating available on some phones, and it's much less grippy than Apple's bumper

Answer (score 0):

Ive manually cut a little bit connector hole in my free bumper case:)